# Get lat/long of Foursquare data

Tags: foursquare

I'm looking for some help with the Foursquare API.  I exported my checkin data and it doesn't have addresses or lat/lon data and that's what I'm looking for.  I do have the venue_ID or fsq_id and was hoping to use the places API to search by ID and get the lat/lon, but I'm only seeing examples of how to feed the API an address (which I don't have).  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best formatted Python, but it works for what I needed and I wanted to share.  I took my data export and grabbed all of the venue IDs and put them in a text file.  I think read through the text file to get the lat/lon for each ID and put it in a CSV file.

```
import requests
import json
import csv

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "YOUR_API_KEY"
}

# define path for products adoc file
path = r'foursquare.csv'

# clear attributes file if exists
c = open(path,'w')
c.close()
csv = open(path, 'a')

with open('ids.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    fsq_id = str(line).replace("\n","")
    url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/"+fsq_id+"?fields=geocodes"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code != 404:
        locations = response.json()
        csv.write(fsq_id)
        csv.write(", ")
        csv.write(str(locations['geocodes']['main']['latitude']))
        csv.write(", ")
        csv.write(str(locations['geocodes']['main']['longitude']))
        csv.write("\n")

print("done")
```

Comment: The endpoint used here is correct -- it's called "Get Place Details" in the documentation.

https://location.foursquare.com/developer/reference/place-details